# How to add items to existing database thru application form

Tags: c#, dataset

I currently have a dataset and would like to continually add new items to that dataset (like type a new entry in a textbox and add it with a button) and edit current items via the applications form I created.

How would I go about tackling this issue?

edit:
This was the best base start I could come up with watching videos and going through google. Dictionary.mdf is my dataset

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into dictionary(word, definition) values(@word, @definition)");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", textBoxWordtoAdd.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@definition", textBoxDefinition.Text);

this.Close();
```

Comment: Show your efforts on this.

Comment: This is a very broad question. You have to show some effort, like what you have tries etc. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. A simple Google search can tell you a lot if this is your first time doing this.

Comment: sorry, i didnt know if my failed codes would be useful posting

Comment: shouldn't there be an ExecuteNonQuery call on cmd at least? As far as your code show you only build a SqlCommand, but don't execute it. Maybe Have a look at [MSDN SqlCommand Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

If you were using Ms Sql Server. Then your code should look something like this:

```
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql =  "insert into dictionary(word, definition) values(@word, @definition)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@word", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = textBoxWordtoAdd.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@definition", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = textBoxDefinition.Text;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

You also need to open a conneciton which I don't see in your code, but I assume you do it somewhere. Just replace the `ConnectionString` in the code with your own connection string.

Comment: Ah yea I have the exectueNonQuery part but it says something is wrong with the connection. I have added the data source(connection with the dataset) to my program as the items i created directly in the dataset show up in my listbox but i dont know what to do to be able to call the connection when i am attempting to add more items

Comment: @John Look at the using line in the example code. Where there is ConnectionString - replace it with the same connection string you are using for the datasource to connect to your database.

Comment: Yes I recognized that and replaced it with (DictionaryConnectionString) and got an error of it not existing in the current context

Comment: @John When I said replace it with you real connection string I meant the real connection string that you used in the datasource. If you go to properties of the datasource it should look something like: "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AddressBook.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

Comment: Oh haha I missed the boat there. Is this whole string located somewhere or do I need to piece it together once I retrieve the server name & data directory?

Comment: well i found the location of it but it gives me errors on a few of the letters throughout the datadirectory saying "unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: ah nevermind, i just added an @ in front and it worked! thanks! time to work on editing the items now, haha

Comment: @John I'm glad I could help, and yeah, you either escape the characters with '\' or put a @ in front of the string....good luck

Comment: And @John since you're new to Stackoverflow, take your time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help if you plan to use it in the future. This is a very specific community with very specific rules. I hope you like it and continue to come back in the future.